# Get https working in simple webservice project[attached]

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, https

I have trubble enable https for a simple webservice project. The service i starting but I can´t browse it at all? Its like it is not really published? If I switch to regular http it works fine.

Finddler respondes with this :

> fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to localhost failed.
>   System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The **WCF log** says nothing more then that the service is started.

Here is a test projekt : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DE992A2C8B8C2EC9!7740&authkey=!APkS4Y9ODK-Y-Lk&ithint=file%2czip

You should be able to switch the certificate against any one you already have.

Edit : The certificate Im using are a selfsigned for testing but that should not matter.

Comment: By binding the certificate to the port and app id in Windows it now works but is this the only way? Is it not possible to set this from the web.config at all? Maybe its possible if I use message instead of transport security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade to bind the port to the certificate like in this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx